# Check that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-\sqrt[3]{n}}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to proof that the series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-\sqrt[3]{n}}$$

Converges?

I actually have no test in mind to apply (or just do not know/see one)

Comment: Are you familiar with the integral test?

Comment: The [Comparison Test](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SeriesCompTest.aspx) works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that we can write

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}\ge \frac{x^6}{6!}$$

for $x>0$.  Hence, we have

$$e^{-n^{1/3}}=\frac{1}{e^{n^{1/3}}}\le \frac{6!}{n^2}$$

And inasmuch as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\pi^2/6$ converges, the series of interest does likewise by comparison.

Comment: Why do you exactly compare $$e^x$$ series with $$\frac{x^6}{6!}$$ ?

Comment: Note that for $x>0$, all of the terms in the Taylor series representation of $e^x$ are positive.  Hence, $e^x$ is greater than or equal to any single term of the series.  In particular, $e^x\ge \frac{x^6}{6!}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Show that $\sqrt[3]{n}\geq 2\ln n$ for large enough $n$.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you may notice that the function $f(x)=\exp\left(-\sqrt[3]{x}\right)$ is decreasing on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}3z^2 f(z^3)\,dz = \int_{0}^{+\infty}3z^2 e^{-z}\,dz = 3\cdot 2! = 6 $$
from which
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}f(n) \leq \int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx = 6. $$

Comment: Please explain the downvote.