# Is the series converging?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{1/3}*e^{-n^{1/2}} $$ How to prove the convergence of this series?  Without using an integral comparison criterion

Comment: A comparison test can indeed be employed. See if the several answers in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2739762/check-the-convergence-using-the-integral-test-for-sum-limits-n-1-infty gives any inspiration.

Comment: Methods described in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2233970/check-that-sum-n-1-infty-e-sqrt3n-converges would also help.

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit your attempts into the question.

Comment: The problem is that I did not know at all how to start it without using the integral feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^a e^{-n^{b}}$; $a,b$ nonzero real numbers,
converges for all choice of nonzero real $a$ and real positive $b$. Including $a=1/3$ and $b=1/2$.

Taking logarithms:

$$e^{n^{-b}} = n^{-\frac{n^{b}}{\ln n}}.$$ One can check that $\frac{n^{b}}{\ln n} > 2-a$ for $n \ge n'(a,b)=4^{5+5/b^2+|a|}$, for example. Thus,

$$0 \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^a e^{-n^{b}} \le \sum_{n=1}^{n'(a,b)}n^a e^{-n^{b}} +\sum_{n \ge n'(a,b)} n^{-2}.$$

Can you finish from here.